# RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSendingEnabled)) Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyf54.png)There's signature popup first time with none enter(signature stoke) close the popup by clicking on cancel button and once more reopening the popup and providing a input(stroke) once after stoke is completed variable is set to true

```
On onpropertychange throwing below excetion

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatButton'.'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2iTP.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbgOL.png)

**Stack Trace**

at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf (Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self) [0x00029] in :0
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00000] in :0
at Android.Views.View.get_Enabled () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/*work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-29/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:6262
at XF.Material.Droid.Renderers.MaterialDrawableHelper.CreateStateListAnimator () [0x00000] in /Users/martijn/Documents/OpenSource/XF-Material-Library/XF.Material/Platforms/Android/Renderers/MaterialDrawableHelper.cs:291
at XF.Material.Droid.Renderers.MaterialDrawableHelper.UpdateElevation () [0x00008] in /Users/martijn/Documents/OpenSource/XF-Material-Library/XF.Material/Platforms/Android/Renderers/MaterialDrawableHelper.cs:286
at XF.Material.Droid.Renderers.MaterialDrawableHelper.BindableButton_PropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00029] in /Users/martijn/Documents/OpenSource/XF-Material-Library/XF.Material/Platforms/Android/Renderers/MaterialDrawableHelper.cs:110
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) .invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs(object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:266
at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:362
at XF.Material.Forms.UI.MaterialButton.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x0001a] in /Users/martijn/Documents/OpenSource/XF-Material-Library/XF.Material/UI/MaterialButton.cs:108
at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00114] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:510
at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x00173] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:446
at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (System.Object sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x00226] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:160
at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x0003e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:56
at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.b__49_0 () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:762
at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.PropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args) [0x000cb] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:773
at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+WeakPropertyChangedProxy.OnPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00012] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:666
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) .invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs(object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
at XamarinUniversity.Infrastructure.SimpleViewModel.RaisePropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00012] in :0
at ICR_MobileApp.ViewModels.SignatureSectionViewModel.OnStrokeCompleted () [0x0001c] in C:\Users\supriya.mecharla\source\repos\ICR_MobileApp\ICR_MobileApp\ICR_MobileApp\ViewModels\SectionViewModels\SignatureSectionViewModel.cs:262
at ICR_MobileApp.ViewModels.SignatureSectionViewModel.<.ctor>b__50_6 () [0x00000] in C:\Users\supriya.mecharla\source\repos\ICR_MobileApp\ICR_MobileApp\ICR_MobileApp\ViewModels\SectionViewModels\SignatureSectionViewModel.cs:168
at Xamarin.Forms.Command+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ctor>b__0 (System.Object o) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Command.cs:74
at Xamarin.Forms.Command.Execute (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Command.cs:112
at SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadCanvasView.OnStrokeCompleted () [0x00039] in :0
at SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadCanvasRenderer.OnStrokeCompleted (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0000a] in :0
at Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePadCanvasView.OnStrokeCompleted (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0000a] in <0c0873655a504a1796935fa2cfa62e06>:0
at Xamarin.Controls.InkPresenter.OnStrokeCompleted () [0x0000a] in <0c0873655a504a1796935fa2cfa62e06>:0
at Xamarin.Controls.InkPresenter.TouchesEnded (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x0003c] in <0c0873655a504a1796935fa2cfa62e06>:0
at Xamarin.Controls.InkPresenter.OnTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x0002e] in <0c0873655a504a1796935fa2cfa62e06>:0
at Android.Views.View.n_OnTouchEvent_Landroid_view_MotionEvent* (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-29/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:18286
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.35(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Please include error messages and other text by **pasting the text**, not as images. Please add to question **stack dump** (as text not as image) at the time the exception happened.